# `yarn storybook` is hanging on `generated-stories-entry.js` for Rails 6 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, storybook

I'm adding storybook (v. 6.3.4) to a Rails 6 application and following [these](https://storybook.js.org/docs/riot/get-started/install) instructions I've installed via the CLI (`npx sb init`) which works fine.

When I run `yarn storybook` I get the following that hangs (have left if for 1+ hours).

```
➜  yarn storybook
yarn run v1.22.10
$ start-storybook -p 6006
info @storybook/react v6.3.4
info
info => Loading presets
info => Loading 1 config file in "/Users/rob/Documents/Projects/ProjectName/.storybook"
info => Loading 9 other files in "/Users/rob/Documents/Projects/ProjectName/.storybook"
info => Adding stories defined in "/Users/rob/Documents/Projects/ProjectName/.storybook/main.js"
info => Using prebuilt manager
info => Using implicit CSS loaders
info => Using custom postcss.config.js
info => Using default Webpack4 setup
(node:43594) DeprecationWarning: Relying on the implicit PostCSS loader is deprecated and will be removed in Storybook 7.0.
If you need PostCSS, include '@storybook/addon-postcss' in your '.storybook/main.js' file.

See https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated-implicit-postcss-loader for details.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
69% building 2544/2546 modules 2 active ...ects/ProjectName/.storybook/generated-stories-entry.js
```

In my `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
```

`yarn build-storybook` works fine.

I have tried removing `node_modules` and running a fresh `yarn install`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey, did you able to get this problem resolved?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone googling this solution, here goes mine.

It seems that a necessary dependency is missing. For example, I needed `expo` as a dependency in my `react-native` app. I removed it when I was cleaning up dependencies.

However, in my project, Storybook depended on it. So, that's why it stopped there. No crash, just an infinite load.

To answer Robert's question, I don't know what his problem was (because I'd need to see his `package.json` file and project). Nevertheless, maybe it is worth trying to find a missing dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a couple things for me. I need to:

1. Use Webpack 5. See [docs for updating](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#webpack-5).
2. Install [babel-plugin-react-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-require) as a dependency

I was finally able to get an error message from the build by doing the following:

1. Comment out everything from `.storybook/main.js` that wasn't needed (all addons, plugins, etc).
2. Remove `.storybook/preview.js`

At this point, I finally got an error message that `babel-plugin-react-require` couldn't be found.